# GWT - FlowPanel and resizing

Tags: gwt, layout, resize

I have several `Composite` widgets in my application that use a `FlowPanel` as their main element. What I want to know is, do I need to take care of resizing in any way for this? `FlowPanel` does not implement `RequiresResize`, so I can't use a `ResizeComposite`, but maybe that means I don't have to? But then how are the widgets inside the `FlowPanel` informed of resizing?

Comment: Is your flowpanel a child of a widget that implements ProvidesResize?

Comment: I'm using this in multiple Widgets, in some of them it is, in some it isn't. I do know that you can't set it as the main Widget of a `ResizeComposite` though, it actually gives an error.

Comment: How are you planning on listening for resize events? Window.onResize?

Comment: I'm not planning to listen for them manually at all. My main UI widget is added to RootLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use FlowPanel as your base composite if you want to let your widgets adapt to your browser window.  Use LayoutPanels instead.

Check this:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html

Comment: Well, the problem with that is, a lot of these are really restrictive; for example, I have to give the size of the components upon adding them to a `DockLayoutPanel`, which means it's difficult to set it from CSS or such.

I will consider this, but honestly, this doesn't really answer my question.