# GWT Widget with layoutpanel-based resizable width but content-based height

Tags: gwt

I'm building a GWT Application with a TabLayoutPanel containing a group  of some kind of a data displaying DisclosurePanel-like widget. These widgets should look a bit like a StackLayoutPanel, but be able to open multiple widgets at the same time. The DisclosurePanel itself is not usable, because it should contain a button in the header (I tried this with a DisclosurePanel, the Button also forces a expand/collapse of the DisclosurePanel). These Widgets should:

- have the same height when closed
- show some more content when opened (and should resize to this content when opened)
- but: the width should be resized to the size of the parentpanel (I thought of a Scrollpanel attached to the TabLayoutPanel)

I'm stuck with the panel I should use for those widgets. The FlowPanel would resize depending on its own content, but not to the size of its parent. The LayoutPanel (as far as I know by the moment) would resize to the size of its parent completely.

I read those two articles while seeking for a solution:

[GWT - FlowPanel and resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802277/gwt-flowpanel-and-resizing)

[Adjusting height of GWT Panels based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859679/adjusting-height-of-gwt-panels-based-on-content)

Now I'm completely overwhelmed :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

FlowPanel resolves to a `div`, so it will take the width of its parent and the height of its content.

And you can always apply CSS to any widget to get the behavior that you want.